# Refer to column with specific Header Name

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I export an excel file (source) every day and I need to link specific columns from this export file to another excel file (reporting). But columns in source file may varied, thus I can not use classic link `=[FileName.xlsx]Sheet!C:C` for example.

Instead of it I need to "find" name of the field (1st row) and refer data beneath it to reporting file.
Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You could probaby

Answer (score 1):

You may use a named range as the target of the link.
You may then use the same name for any part of the document,
which the hyperlink will position to and select.

[image]

For more information, see the article
[Fix Excel Hyperlinks to a Named Range](https://www.myexcelonline.com/blog/fix-excel-hyperlinks-named-range/).

Answer (score 0):

Using CELL("address" with INDEX(MATCH might get you started. You could use this to determine the column then work with indirect to use it in your formula.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`XLOOKUP` can resolve this for you.

Depending on how you manipulate the data within the reporting file, you may want to create a separate tab (or area on that tab) where you first pull in the data from the columns you want, in the order you're expecting. You can create that "data formatting/cleaning" tab very easily -- just take an existing example of your report file that's linked to the raw data, and move-tab or ctrl-x the raw data into your report file. Then clean up that data just how you want it (with all the columns you want in the order you want). Then you can replace that actual data with an XLOOKUP formula that looks to the raw data file. Each day you can swap out the underlying raw data file, and your spreadsheet will now automatically pull the new data in in your pre-defined format, which your reporting tab will be linked to.

To use `XLOOKUP`, you simply tell it to look for a specific value across a row, and find it in a single column. Then Excel will let you pull in the data from any other row in that same column. See the example below for the easiest way to use `XLOOKUP` in this instance. In this simplified example, the stuff on the left is the raw data and the stuff on the right is like your formatted data that the reporting tab will work on. You just need to put that formula in the top left cell, and you can paste it it down and to the right to pull in as many rows from as many different columns as you care to define.
The key input from you is the name of the column, which you need to fill in and  I've indicate in blue.
If you don't know how many rows you'll need, just copy it down way longer than you think you'll need so you don't miss anything. If the number of rows is so large that that takes too long to process, then there are ways to identify the the number of rows in the raw data, but that's rarely needed so I won't address it here.

[image]

The image shows:

Input data in `A4:D8`, with row 4 containing column headers.

Output in `F4:G15`.
The two columns of interest, Name and City, have their headers manually entered into cells `F4` and `G4`. The XLOOKUP formula is entered into cell `F5`, the first non-header cell of the output range. The formula in cell `F5` is:
`=XLOOKUP(F$4,$A$4:$D$4,$A5:$D5)`

Note the anchoring (dollar signs) used in the formula, as it's critical for the formula to work correctly over the entire output range.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `INDEX()` for this. The following will produce a full dynamic output with the single formula, so no copying and pasting over and down:

```
=INDEX(A5:D8,  SEQUENCE( ROWS(A5:D8) ),  MATCH(F4:G4,A4:D4,0)  )
```

(I'm using `bigjoec`'s example for the formula.)

`MATCH()` will generate the proper column numbers, in the order in the output table's headers. It is a dynamic array, in this case producing `{4,2}` internally to the formula.

Because you specify the columns in that manner, you have to specify the rows as well, not leave that parameter empty or use a `0` for it. If you don't have `SEQUENCE()`, use the old-style `ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS(A5:D8)))`.

And that's that. You can use `FILTER()` to produce an output, but the trick is organizing the columns in the output table's order. Of course, that can be done using `FILTER()` to generate the data, then `INDEX()` to reorganize the columns, but why bother if you can just do the above?

Answer (score 0):

If possible, just name the column reference in the source file, say *data1* (using Formulas > Define name), then in the destination sheet use:

```
=[FileName.xlsx]Sheet!data1
```

*data1* will automatically move or otherwise change, as you insert or delete new columns in the sheet.

FYI, using whole column references ($C:$C) is a generally a very bad idea, as Excel will need to load all ~1million cells into memory every time you call it. Luckily you can define *data1* as say `=$C$1:INDEX($C:$C,COUNTA($C:$C))`. This is called a *dynamic named range* and will return a reference to only the USED RANGE in C (assuming contiguous data without blanks). While it also uses whole column references, Excel cleverly only recalculates this named range if the source data in C changes (its a *non-volatile* formula). Even if you call the named range many times over, the used range has already been calculated and the answer available for use without the massive memory penalty.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot used the named range concept in my other answer (say because you overwrite and not insert new data and don't want to edit the named range, or just have impractically many columns to name), you can use INDEX:INDEX to create a **non-volatile** reference to the other workbook. **Avoid** using OFFSET or INDIRECT or making whole copies of the source data in your destination file, as this will slow down your workbook considerably.

First find your column (let call this *colindex*):

```
=MATCH("My Column", [FileName.xlsx]Sheet!A1:Z1, 0)
```

Then use INDEX:INDEX to create your reference:

```
=INDEX([FileName.xlsx]Sheet!A2:Z2, 1,colindex):INDEX([FileName.xlsx]Sheet!A10000:Z10000, 1, colindex)
```

Where you can substitute Z or 10000 for any maximum number of columns/rows you might expect, all the way up to XFD / 1048576.

Comment: PS. If you are going to be using  this reference many times over, you can create both colindex and the INDEX:INDEX formula as named ranges in your destination sheet. If you have Excel 365 and the LET function, you can combine it all into one: `=LET(colindex, MATCH(...), INDEX(..., colindex):INDEX(..., colindex))`